# Copy primary keys/clustered indexes from Prod to DEv/Test env

Tags: sql-server-2012, primary-key, clustered-index

We followed the best practices of creating Primary Keys/Clustered indexes on tables which are actively queried on prod.

Now there is a scenario where we need to get the similar above changes done onto DEV/test. Since we did not expect we might require this on dev, we never documented so as to map similar changes.

Is there a better and faster way of doing this rather than , manually scripting out and creating them henceforth.

Thanks.

Comment: Uh, backup production and restore it to dev?

Comment: Paparazzi@ Well, that is not acceptable for developer as they have their development phase in process for similar database out there on dev env

Comment: You can right click in SSMS and create the script.  You will need to edit out what you don't need.   You missed PKs the first time?

Comment: I am so confused.  You guys make changes in production then bring them DOWN to Dev?  Is this a 1 time thing?  Are you guys starting a new process here?  I just want to get clarity before I share the powershell scripts I use to make sure I'm giving you what you need.  Also, what is your dev environment like?  It looks like a static shared dev and QA environment.  Any chance of making it much more useful and update-able?

Comment: @AliRazeghi- I know its sort of weird and flows backward in terms of process. But this is just one time activity. Since it was missed on DEV first , and was done from STG to PROD. We need this to replicate the changes on DEV. DEV is something we have got as new env instead of staging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a start unless this was an absolute emergency you have done everything backwards: you should not make changes to production that have not been made in dev/test first to make sure they have the desired effect. Develop, test, *then* release the changes to production.

Setting that aside: There are a number of tools out there that claim to compare schema, and some try to generate a script to bring one schema into sync with another reference one (though I'd be wary of running such a generated script without a detailed review first!).

http://opendbdiff.codeplex.com/ came up in a quick search though I've not used the project myself. It seems to fit the need you describe. There are also products from RedGate & other SQL related software houses (search for "schema compare") and a tool built in to some editions of Visual Studio which your developers may already have available.

Comment: Thanks David, the DBDiff works, but it involves little manual tasks of finding the appropriate and retracking the changes that happened